# How to call a list from app.js to a component in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, object, react-state

I am trying to set a state in a component and transfer that list from one component to another. But getting console error as List.map() is not a function!

I am trying to get webpage as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DF2HR.png) using react js

App.js :

```
import GoogleSuggestions from './components/GoogleSuggestions'

import './App.css'

const suggestionsList = [
  {id: 1, suggestion: 'Price of Ethereum'},
  {id: 2, suggestion: 'Oculus Quest 2 specs'},
  {id: 3, suggestion: 'Tesla Share Price'},
  {id: 4, suggestion: 'Price of Ethereum today'},
  {id: 5, suggestion: 'Latest trends in AI'},
  {id: 6, suggestion: 'Latest trends in ML'},
]

const App = () => <GoogleSuggestions suggestionsList={suggestionsList} />

export default App
```

components/GoogleSuggestions :

```
// Write your code here
import {Component} from 'react'

import SuggestionItem from '../SuggestionItem'

import './index.css'

class GoogleSuggestions extends Component {
  state = {suggestionsList: this.props, searchInput: ''}

  showoptions = event => {
    this.setState({searchInput: event.target.value})
  }

  render() {
    const {suggestionsList, searchInput} = this.state
    console.log(typeof suggestionsList)
    return (
      <div className="bg-container">
        <img
          className="googleLogo"
          src="https://assets.ccbp.in/frontend/react-js/google-logo.png"
          alt="google logo"
        />
        <div className="input-container">
          <div>
            <img
              className="search-icon"
              src="https://assets.ccbp.in/frontend/react-js/google-search-icon.png"
              alt="search icon"
            />
            <input
              type="search"
              value={searchInput}
              onClick={this.showoptions}
              className="input"
              placeholder="Search Google"
            />
          </div>
          <ul className="ul-cont">
            {suggestionsList.map(eachItem => (
              <SuggestionItem itemDetails={eachItem} key={eachItem.id} />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default GoogleSuggestions
```

SuggestionItem

```
// Write your code here 
import {Component} from 'react' 
import './index.css'  
class SuggestionItem extends Component {
   render() {
     const {itemDetails} = this.props
     const {id, suggestion} = itemDetails
     return (
       <li>
         <div className="Item-cont">
           <p>{suggestion}</p>
           <img
             src="https://assets.ccbp.in/frontend/react-js/diagonal-arrow-left-up.png"
             alt="arrow"
           />
         </div>
       </li>
     )
   }
}
export default SuggestionItem
```

I am expecting to send list to component/GoogleSuggestions but getting as object.

Answer (score 2):

Not `state = {suggestionsList: this.props, searchInput: ''}`.

You should use `state = {suggestionsList: this.props.suggestionsList, searchInput: ''}`

And You can use `onChange={this.showoptions}` for searchEngine not `onClick={this.showoptions}`

Here is right `GoogleSuggestions.js` File

```
// Write your code here
import {Component} from 'react'

import SuggestionItem from './SuggestionItem'


class GoogleSuggestions extends Component {
  state = {suggestionsList: this.props.suggestionsList, searchInput: ''}

  showoptions = event => {
    this.setState({searchInput: event.target.value})
  }

  render() {
    const {suggestionsList, searchInput} = this.state
    console.log(suggestionsList);
    console.log(typeof suggestionsList)
    return (
      <div className="bg-container">
        <img
          className="googleLogo"
          src="https://assets.ccbp.in/frontend/react-js/google-logo.png"
          alt="google logo"
        />
        <div className="input-container">
          <div>
            <img
              className="search-icon"
              src="https://assets.ccbp.in/frontend/react-js/google-search-icon.png"
              alt="search icon"
            />
            <input
              type="search"
              value={searchInput}
              onClick={this.showoptions}
              className="input"
              placeholder="Search Google"
            />
          </div>
          <ul className="ul-cont">
            {suggestionsList.map(eachItem => (
              <SuggestionItem itemDetails={eachItem} key={eachItem.id} />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default GoogleSuggestions
// Write your code here
import {Component} from 'react'

import SuggestionItem from './SuggestionItem'


class GoogleSuggestions extends Component {
  state = {suggestionsList: this.props.suggestionsList, searchInput: ''}

  showoptions = event => {
    this.setState({searchInput: event.target.value})
    console.log(this.state.searchInput);
  }

  render() {
    const {suggestionsList, searchInput} = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="bg-container">
        <img
          className="googleLogo"
          src="https://assets.ccbp.in/frontend/react-js/google-logo.png"
          alt="google logo"
        />
        <div className="input-container">
          <div>
            <img
              className="search-icon"
              src="https://assets.ccbp.in/frontend/react-js/google-search-icon.png"
              alt="search icon"
            />
            <input
              type="search"
              value={searchInput}
              onChange={this.showoptions}
              className="input"
              placeholder="Search Google"
            />
          </div>
          <ul className="ul-cont">
            {suggestionsList.map(eachItem => (
              eachItem.suggestion.indexOf(searchInput) ? "":<SuggestionItem itemDetails={eachItem} key={eachItem.id} /> 
              
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default GoogleSuggestions
```

Answer (score 1):

You're assigning your list incorrectly in your child component. It should be `this.props.suggestionsList`

```
class GoogleSuggestions extends Component {
  state = {suggestionsList: this.props.suggestionsList, searchInput: ''}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign all props to state instead of only `suggestionsList`.

Also, you don't need to put `suggestionsList` to state. It makes additional variable mutable and can lead to potential bugs. Just use it from props directly.

Try this:

```
// Write your code here
import {Component} from 'react'

import SuggestionItem from '../SuggestionItem'

import './index.css'

class GoogleSuggestions extends Component {
  state = { searchInput: ''}

  showoptions = event => {
    this.setState({searchInput: event.target.value})
  }

  render() {
    const {suggestionsList, searchInput} = this.state
    const { suggestionsList } = this.props;
    console.log(typeof suggestionsList)
    return (
      <div className="bg-container">
        <img
          className="googleLogo"
          src="https://assets.ccbp.in/frontend/react-js/google-logo.png"
          alt="google logo"
        />
        <div className="input-container">
          <div>
            <img
              className="search-icon"
              src="https://assets.ccbp.in/frontend/react-js/google-search-icon.png"
              alt="search icon"
            />
            <input
              type="search"
              value={searchInput}
              onClick={this.showoptions}
              className="input"
              placeholder="Search Google"
            />
          </div>
          <ul className="ul-cont">
            {suggestionsList.map(eachItem => (
              <SuggestionItem itemDetails={eachItem} key={eachItem.id} />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default GoogleSuggestions
```